# Wildcards in the pattern for http.HandleFunc

Tags: regex, http, go

When registering handlers, is there any way to specify wildcards in the pattern?

For example:

```
http.HandleFunc("/groups/*/people", peopleInGroupHandler)
```

Where the `*` could be any valid URL string.  Or is the only solution to match `/groups` and figure the rest out from within the handler (`peopleInGroupHandler`) func?

Comment: May I see an example of your input string, and what you're currently getting for matches please?

Comment: See http://goweb.googlecode.com/ that provides support for Ruby on Rails style routes in Go - i.e. goweb.MapFunc("/people/{person_id}/groups/{group_id}", handler)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The patterns for http.Handler and http.HandleFunc aren't regular expressions or globs. There isn't a way to specify wildcards. They're documented [here](http://golang.org/pkg/http/#ServeMux).

That said, it's not too hard to create your own handler that can use regular expressions or any other kind of pattern you want. Here's one that uses regular expressions (compiled, but not tested):

```
type route struct {
    pattern *regexp.Regexp
    handler http.Handler
}

type RegexpHandler struct {
    routes []*route
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) Handler(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler http.Handler) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, handler})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) HandleFunc(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, http.HandlerFunc(handler)})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.pattern.MatchString(r.URL.Path) {
            route.handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
    }
    // no pattern matched; send 404 response
    http.NotFound(w, r)
}
```

Comment: As I wanted ruby on rails style routes in Go, I have started the goweb project (see http://goweb.googlecode.com/) that allows this style of route mapping:

    goweb.MapFunc("/people/{person_id}", handler)

Comment: Gorillatoolkit does a great job of implementing PAT and MUX for processing routes. The only problem is that it is slow and I have yet to review the code. At least in their API it's possible to name the params... which is the whole point of that sort of functionality. The code above does not provide anything that sophisticated and is likely not useful without named elements.

Comment: If you're merely looking for an "otherwise" `*`-like catch-all, something to note from [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) is that `the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns`

Comment: Maybe `(h *RegexpHandler) Handler` should be `(h *RegexpHandler) Handle`? See here: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.Handle :)

Comment: @Coaku It's ok to use `(h *RegexpHandler) Handler` here because only the method `ServeHTTP` of `RegexpHandler` matters.

Comment: How can I integrate the code into the original example of `net/http`. Can you give a complete example? Thx.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just submitted an answer with an example using your code.

Answer (score 64):

Since 2011, you can now (2014+) find other solutions.
For instance, the [mux package of the Gorilla Web toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) provides all kind of routing options:

- Pattern matching on request paths, with optional regular expressions.
- Matching on URL host and scheme, request method, header and query values.
- Matching based on custom functions.
- Use of sub-routers for easy nested routing.

It can be easily integrated to any BYOR (Bring your own Router) http library, [like negroni](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni#routing).

Here is an example from the article "[Gorilla vs Pat vs Routes: A Mux Showdown](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/a-mux-showdown)":

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  rtr := mux.NewRouter()
  rtr.HandleFunc("/user/{name:[a-z]+}/profile", profile).Methods("GET")

  http.Handle("/", rtr)

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func profile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  params := mux.Vars(r)
  name := params["name"]
  w.Write([]byte("Hello " + name))
}
```

> Sometimes better not to just use yet another "magic" package, but understand what's going on under the hood

In this instance, the "magic" is defined in "[`gorilla/mux/regexp.go`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/regexp.go)", and [tested here](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/mux_test.go#L294-L381).
The idea is to extract named variables, assemble a regexp to be matched, create a "reverse" template to build URLs and compile regexps to validate variable values used in URL building.

Comment: Because it is much newer. Give it time :)

Comment: Because sometimes better not to just use yet another "magic" package, but understand what's going on under the hood :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example of how to use the code example from @evanshaw

```
func handleDigits(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    res.Write([]byte("Digits in the URL\n"))
}

func handleStrings(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    res.Write([]byte("Strings in the URL\n"))
}

func main() {
    handler := &RegexpHandler{}

    reg1, _ := regexp.Compile("/foo-\\d+")
    handler.HandleFunc(reg1, handleDigits)

    reg2, _ := regexp.Compile("/foo-\\w+")
    handler.HandleFunc(reg2, handleStrings)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handler)
}
```

Comment: cannot use reg2 (type *regexp.Regexp) as type string i│
n argument to http.HandleFunc

Comment: @CSQGB If you read the answer properly it says "Here's an example of how to use the code example from @evanshaw" its not just code. This uses an example from above. It even uses a different handler called `RegexpHandler`, not an `http.HandleFunc`.

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to add `julienschmidt/httprouter`, which just behaves like `net/http` but with an additional parameter for url-values and support for request methods:

https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
}

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!\n", ps.ByName("name"))
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)
    router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

It also seems to be slightly more popular than `gorilla/mux` (according to GitHub) and it also claims to need less memory.

https://github.com/julienschmidt/go-http-routing-benchmark

Answer (score 1):

You could check how [violetear](https://violetear.org/) handles dynamic + catchall (wildcard) patterns, this is just for complement for example:

```
uuid := `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}`
router.AddRegex(":uuid")
router.HandleFunc("/test/:uuid/:uuid", handleUUID, "GET,HEAD")
```

In this case, the request may have 2 different `UUIDS`

For a dynamic/wildcard this could apply:

```
http://api.violetear.org/command/ping/127.0.0.1
                        \______/\___/\________/
                            |     |      |
                             static      |
                                      dynamic
```

A regex may be used to match the IP:

```
router.AddRegex(":ip", `^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$`)
router.HandleFunc("/command/ping/:ip", ipHandler, "GET")
```

Or simply just a catch all allowing `GET` and `HEAD` methods only:

```
router.HandleFunc("/command/ping/*", anyHandler, "GET, HEAD")
```

More examples can be found here: https://violetear.org/post/how-it-works/

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are usually not specified when registering handlers.

Routes containing wildcards are maintained in a route table, compiled based on user input, and then passed to the appropriate handler function.

I came across [Ben Hoyt's blog on HTTP routing in Go](https://benhoyt.com/writings/go-routing) in which he describes and compares custom techniques with third-party ones. I would highly recommend anyone reading this to go through it. Also, [Gorilla'x mux package is now archived](https://github.com/gorilla/mux)

The below approach is based on regex table, in which we loop through pre-compiled regexes and pass matches using the request context.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var routes = []route{
    newRoute("GET", "/", home),
    newRoute("GET", "/([^/]+)", sink),
    newRoute("GET", "/groups/([^/]+)/people", peopleInGroupHandler),
}

func newRoute(method, pattern string, handler http.HandlerFunc) route {
    return route{method, regexp.MustCompile("^" + pattern + "$"), handler}
}

type route struct {
    method  string
    regex   *regexp.Regexp
    handler http.HandlerFunc
}

func Serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var allow []string
    for _, route := range routes {
        matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
        if len(matches) > 0 {
            if r.Method != route.method {
                allow = append(allow, route.method)
                continue
            }
            ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctxKey{}, matches[1:])
            route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
            return
        }
    }
    if len(allow) > 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", strings.Join(allow, ", "))
        http.Error(w, "405 method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    http.NotFound(w, r)
}

type ctxKey struct{}

func getField(r *http.Request, index int) string {
    fields := r.Context().Value(ctxKey{}).([]string)
    return fields[index]
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "HOME\n")
}

func peopleInGroupHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    slug := getField(r, 0)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Group handler: %s\n", slug)
}

func sink(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    slug := getField(r, 0)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sink %s\n", slug)
}


func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", http.HandlerFunc(Serve))
}
```

Example requests and responses

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080
HOME

curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/
HOME

curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/temp
Sink temp

curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/groups/south-park/people
People in group south-park

curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/groups/6/people
People in group 6
```

---