# Go: add username to URL

Tags: go

How do I add the username of the current user, or other variables, to the end of the URL path in Go?

I tried using a http.Redirect(w, "/home/"+user, http.StatusFound), but that would create an infinite redirect loop.

Go:

```
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    randIndex = rand.Intn(len(cityLibrary))
    ImageDisplay()
    WeatherDisplay()
    dispdata = AllApiData{Images: imagesArray, Weather: &WeatherData{Temp: celsiusNum, City: cityLibrary[randIndex], RainShine: rainOrShine}}

    //http.Redirect(w, "/"+cityLibrary[randIndex], http.StatusFound) --> infinite redirect loop

    renderTemplate(w, "home", dispdata)
    }

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)

    http.Handle("/layout/", http.StripPrefix("/layout/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("layout"))))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

In this code, I'm trying to append the value of "City" to the end of the root URL. Should I be using regexp?

Comment: What's the rest of your code look like? The router and handlers?

Comment: added the code above.

Comment: Where is your handler for `/{city}/` urls?

Comment: I don't have it. I didn't know how to construct it using regexp.

Comment: one sec I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is happening because you don't have a `/{city}/` handler and the `/` handler is matching all the requests being redirected to cities :

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.
>
> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

What you need to do is put in the city url handler, if you need to handle RegEx patterns take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565407/220710) or you could use a more powerful router like [gorilla's `mux`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux).

---

> what just using Go without gorilla? I know how to do it in Gorilla but I'm just wondering how its done in Go.

You make your own custom handlers with as mentioned in the previously mentioned answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565407/220710

```
type route struct {
    pattern *regexp.Regexp
    handler http.Handler
}

type RegexpHandler struct {
    routes []*route
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) Handler(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler http.Handler) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, handler})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) HandleFunc(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, http.HandlerFunc(handler)})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.pattern.MatchString(r.URL.Path) {
            route.handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
    }
    // no pattern matched; send 404 response
    http.NotFound(w, r)
}
```

To use this then you would do something like this :

```
import regexp

...

rex := RegexpHandler{}
rex.HandlerFunc(regexp.MustCompile("^/(\w+?)/?"), cityHandler) // cityHandler is your regular handler function
rex.HandlerFunc(regexp.MustCompile("^/"), homeHandler)
http.Handle("/", &rex)
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

Comment: thanks. What do I put in place of {city} since it is a variable?

Comment: @user3918985 If you are using gorilla's `mux` you can just use something like this `r.HandleFunc("/articles/{city}/", CityHandler)` read the documentation here : http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux

Comment: what just using Go without gorilla? I know how to do it in Gorilla but I'm just wondering how its done in Go.

Comment: @user3918985 I added an example of how to use a RegEx handler, accept the answer if it is what you wanted.

Comment: Note, you can also get the city in `r.HandleFunc("/articles/{city}/", CityHandler)`, by simply splitting `req.URL.Path` in `CityHandler` by `/`. `{city}` would be in `splits[1]`.