# how to oragnize handlers in go as project gets bigger?

Tags: go

I am building a website with `Go` and I know how it works and how to handle routes with `handlefunc()`. however, my website is getting bigger and I will probably have alot of urls. the question is how to handle all this ? I cannot just add for example 100+ or 500+ `handelfunc()` in my `main()` to match each possible route or url for example. so how to manage it ? thanks in advance.

**NOTE ::**

my question doesn't require any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely should not put 500+ `HandleFunc` in your main.

To begin with, as the project goes bigger you'll probably create modules and types.

You can then delegate to these modules or types from your `main` so that then each module or type would then register handles themselves.

Also, probably many of your URLs will follow patterns, such as:

```
"/articles/{id}"
```

If that's the case, you should just register that pattern once, and then the function handling the request can operate based on the parameter `{id}`.

There are several libraries out there that can help manage the routing if using patterns, or you can also code your own routing logic.

Take a look at this question for some alternatives on that matter:

[Wildcards in the pattern for http.HandleFunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564558/wildcards-in-the-pattern-for-http-handlefunc)

For example, if you where using `Chi` (https://github.com/pressly/chi) to manage the routing, in your main you can do:

```
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Mount("/admin", adminRouter())
```

And then inside that `adminRouter()` function you keep creating handlers that will be served under `/admin`:

```
func adminRouter() http.Handler {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(AdminOnly)
    r.Get("/", adminIndex)
    r.Get("/accounts", adminListAccounts)
    return r
}
```

(all this is taken from Chi's documentation)

This is just an example, you can implement similar logic using a different way.

Comment: you mean main have handlers to modules and inside each modules i can go deeper and add handlers that navigate deeper ?

Comment: yes, I updated my answer with a more concrete example

Comment: can i make different folders and handlers navigate to a certain function in them like django in python for example ? or it is not good approach ? as i dont want to use chis i wantto use my own logic

Comment: take a look at the linked answer for a basic example of how to implement your own router. you can end up implementing something similar to how django works but it will be quite an effort. also, even if you don't use a framework, you can take a look at their source code to see how they go about nesting the routers